# Element stop is missing required attribute offset on SVG Linear Gradient Fill

Tags: svg, gradient, offset

W3 Validation is throwing up the following error:-

```
Element stop is missing required attribute offset
```

On this code:-

```
<!--  Defining Angle Gradient Colors  -->
<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
<!-- Colours red #ca3b37 gold #f0a635 blue #4fc4f6 green #0FBD46-->
<linearGradient id="cl1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
<stop stop-color="#ca3b37"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ca3b37"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop stop-color="#ca3b37"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f0a635"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl3" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop stop-color="#f0a635"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4fc4f6"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl4" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
<stop stop-color="#4fc4f6"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4fc4f6"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl5" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
<stop stop-color="#4fc4f6"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0FBD46"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl6" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
<stop stop-color="#0FBD46"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0FBD46"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Can anyone please advise what the missing attribute is / how it is applied.

Thanks

Glennyboy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some stop elements have an offset attribute in your example, some don't. You need to add an offset attribute to all the ones that don't.

```
<stop stop-color="#ca3b37"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ca3b37"/>
```

becomes

```
<stop offset="<some value you need to decide on>" stop-color="#ca3b37"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ca3b37"/>
```

where you replace <some value you need to decide on> with a value, perhaps 0.

Comment: Ah gotcha. In my case the first offset needed to be offset="0%" , but thank you for pointing out the issue (now blindingly obvious :-)